# open corel draw files on debian

Tags: images, image-manipulation

So I have `.cdr` files on my PC and I want to open them on my Debian 7 box. What software do I need to be able to open it?`

I have:

- 512 MB RAM
- 3 GHz processor
- 256 MB graphics
- with Debian 7

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Gimp

I would see if you can open the `.cdr` files with [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org/). According [to this page Gimp supports editing](http://extension.nirsoft.net/cdr) these files. Gimp should be available in the Debian repos, look for the name `gimp`.

I downloaded this sample image, [cup.cdr (uncompressed 18K)](http://product.corel.com/en/draw/10/tutorials/draw/html_docs/HTMLPics/cup.cdr), from this [Corel website](http://product.corel.com/en/draw/10/tutorials/draw/html_docs/popups/pop_logo_download.htm). However I wasn't able to open it, there might be a plugin for Gimp.

#### Inkscape

The other method you could try (which worked for me) is to convert the `.cdr` image using the command line tool `uniconvertor`, and then open it up in [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/).

```
$ uniconvertor cup.cdr cup.svg
```

Once you've created the `.svg` file you simply open it in Inkscape.

[image: ss of inkscape]

If you don't want to try the above, you can take a look at the Inkscape FAQ, there is a guide on how to import `.cdr` files as well. The FAQ section is titled: [Can I open/import *.cdr (Corel Draw Vector drawing file) files in Inkscape?](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Frequently_asked_questions#Can_I_open.2Fimport_.2A.cdr_.28Corel_Draw_Vector_drawing_file.29_files_in_Inkscape.3F).

#### Your mileage may vary?

I found this thread regarding the conversion process.

*excerpt*

> On Tue, Jan 17, 2012 at 3:20 AM, Sveinn í Felli wrote:
>
> > Inkscape can import some versions of .CDR files (ver. 7-X4), from there one
> >     can export/save as .SVG. Don't know if there are bugs in that process (e.g.
> >     multipage documents, text/font problems, etc.)
>
> Inkscape uses the very same converter as Scribus. It's called
>   UniConvertor and only supports paths with flat fills and strokes (and
>   maybe bitmaps, but I'm not entirely sure). There has been no progress
>   re CDR support in UC in last few years (the primary developer is busy
>   rewriting things yet again), and unfortunately I don't see it changing
>   any time soon.
>
> However there has been quite a bit of progress on reverse-engineering
>   CDR recently on the re-lab side recently, and hopefully things will
>   change now that there is libcdr by one of LibreOffice developers.

*source: http://lists.scribus.info/pipermail/scribus/2012-January/045476.html*

Comment: not an answer :-(

Comment: @Utkarsh - can you elaborate? Did you get some sort of error message? Are your `.cdr` files special in some kind of way?

Answer (score 3):

I was able to open a corel draw .cdr file perfectly using LibreOffice Draw, no file conversion needed. I had no such luck with converting to .svg and opening in Inkscape.

Comment: Yup. This worked for me even after uniconverter failed complaining of a corrupt file and Inkscape & Gimp also failed.